# python scrapy how to know visited links

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

lets say i am scraping over thousands of pages.

Then, when i scrap on a page, i want to know if this page has been scraped before. Then, i decided if i scrap on it or not.

I want to know if scrapy by default save the scraped pages or not.

#### what i have tried

i save the scraped links in a file, then i read it to know if a specific link has been scraped before. However, i think that scrapy should have a build-in feature to do that.

right?

Answer (score 1):

scrapy has that functionality built in and will filter those requests for you, see [scrapy request in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

> **dont_filter** (boolean) – indicates that this request should not be filtered by the scheduler. This is used when you want to perform an identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use it with care, or you will get into crawling loops. Default to False.

so when creating requests you can decide if you want to recrawl the same url or not.

for more implementation info see the default [RFPDupeFilter](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/dupefilter.py#L28) in the code

there is a settings entry called [DUPEFILTER_CLASS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) in case you wish to replace the default one with some other dedup logic

Comment: you mean some explanation of how RFPDupeFilter works? its a very short and simple code, isn't it?

Comment: for me it is not. i am new to python and scrapy and I must do this functionality cos i asked to do that

Comment: do you think you have to add a new duplicate filter? what is your requirements?

Comment: i have many pages like this `website?page=1` , `website?page=2`..... `website?page=n` and each page have many links. I want to scrap on these links in side each page. Also, i want to always scrap  on the pages but not on the links inside them because the content of the pages will change each hour. for example now a specific link is existed in page 2 but after an hour this link will be in page 3 because new items will be added. got me?

Comment: please note that I can scrap on pages and links inside them

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I don't think there is a way to know if its the same page that changed its url, or if its another page, unless you fetch the page and see whats inside

Comment: the links will not change. the content of each page will change. but the content will not change. for example. the `page=1` have these players `player1`, `players2`, and `player3`. each player have a link when you press it, you will see all his information. However, after an hour, the `player1` will be in `page=2` so i don't scrap him because i already did. that is what i mean. ** so i dont have to check the content of each player, the link will be enought **

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45488/discussion-between-guy-and-marco-dinatsoli)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45488/discussion-between-guy-and-marco-dinatsoli

Comment: Sorry for being late, my computer crashed suddenly and now i can continue

Comment: I asked the question again here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203920/python-scrapy-how-to-use-basedupefilter

Comment: Something strange, this converstaion between you and me is here http://queforum.com/python/553305-python-python-scrapy-how-know-visited-links.html