# scrapy: how to skip prior scraped links using LinkExtractor?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

new to scrapy -

I have a list of links which were scraped earlier and would like LinkExtractor to skip them if they are found in a response. I could not find a way to pass any parameter to LinkExtractor to skip links.

Is it possible OR is there a better way to achieve this?

```
import hashlib
from datetime import date
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.utils import python


class FollowAllDomains(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'follow_all'

    start_urls = ['https://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_domains='www.youtube.com'), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
    filename = 'links.txt'

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # print(python.to_unicode(response.body))
        self.check_dupes(response)

    def read_hash_list(self, filename=None):
        # TODO : Avoid multiple file reads - Change to in-mem cache or queue
        hash_list = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            day, key, uri = line.split('|')
            hash_list.append(key)
        return hash_list

    def write_hash_list(self, curr_url, filename=None):
        # hexdigest is a one-way function i.e. no way to decode back to orig site address
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            link_key = hashlib.md5(curr_url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() + '|'
            f.write(str(date.today())+'|')
            f.write(link_key)
            f.write(str(curr_url)+'\n')

    def check_dupes(self, response):
        new = False
        hash_list = self.read_hash_list(self.filename)
        new_hash = hashlib.md5(response.url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        if new_hash not in hash_list:
            self.write_hash_list(response.url, self.filename)
            new = True
        return new
```

I thought of using process_value but there doesn't seem to be any examples similar to what I am trying to do.

Also read this [python scrapy how to know visited links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188038/python-scrapy-how-to-know-visited-links) but i could not understand how it works.

Comment: The link is correct, scrapy already has a duplicate filter built-in, so if the linkextractor does come across the same link it won't follow it more than once, unless you explicitly set the dont_filter parameter to True.

Comment: correct it would ignore duplicates for the current session but how do I tell linkextractor to ignore links which were scraped earlier (e.g. a week ago) ?